# How do I splice a scalar variable?

Tags: perl

```
$ab = "asljdhashdklasjkl ;dajs;ld";
```

I want the first 10 characters from `$ab`.

Can the `splice` function be used?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
substr($ab, 0, 10)
```

Read more about the `substr` function [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

Comment: use 4-arg substr instead of lvalue substr

Comment: This was intended as a rvalue. He wants to get the first 10 chars, not replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Substr works great for your example.  Splice operates on an array, so you would need to round trip it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($ab, @ab, @first_ten, $first_ten);

$ab = "asljdhashdklasjkl ;dajs;ld";

@ab = split(//, $ab);
@first_ten = splice(@ab, 0, 10);

$first_ten = join('', @first_ten);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
my $info = "asljdhashdklasjkl ;dajs;ld";
my @personal = split(//, $info);
print @personal[0..9];


C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>perl perltest.pl
asljdhashd
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>type perltest.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $info = "asljdhashdklasjkl ;dajs;ld";
my @personal = split(//, $info);
print @personal[0..9];
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Comment: The `print` statement won't work unless you have the array slice in double quotes. Even then, it'll print the characters space-separated by default.

Comment: @Zaid..i have tested this and its working.Please check whether you are correct in your statement!!!